# How to let if statement complete even if there is a NullPointerError

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I have this if statement:

```java
if (!this.updateTime.equals(ProductionBlocking
          .get(this.keyReader.getUpdateTime(this.config.configUuid.toString(),
              KeyType.PLUSSTAR)))) {
...
}
```

Sometimes the below is null so I get a NullPointerError.

```java
ProductionBlocking
          .get(this.keyReader.getUpdateTime(this.config.configUuid.toString(),
              KeyType.PLUSSTAR))`
```

Is there any way I can let the program run on even if there is a null pointer? Basically in this case I'd like the if to determine they arent equal.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace you get and which exacly field is null. Also, I think what you're getting is a `NullPointerException`, not some mysterious `NullPointerError`.

Comment: `ProductionBlocking.get(...)` being null wouldn't raise a NullPointerException. `this.updateTime`, `this.keyReader`, `this.config` or `this.config.configUuid` being null would

Comment: What exact part is `null`? Handle that specific part differently.

Comment: If the code you posted would be null, then the equals would evaluate to `false`, because `anything.equals(null)` is always supposed to be `false`, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). I highly suspect that sth else in this statement is `null`, please go over your code with a debugger and update the question.

Comment: Rather than finding a way to ignore the NPE, you should figure out what is causing the NPE and fix it. Something is null, and you need to identify what.

Comment: @Nightara you don't know what `updateTime` is and how it's class might override `equals`. But it *shouldn't* throw an NPE.

Comment: See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @f1sh Edited my comment, realized that myself right after typing it, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the NullPointerException and then do nothing with it... although this is generally not recommended. You *should* try to handle this exception in the catch block and try to figure out *why* you are getting a npe and fix that.

```
try {
    // your code that throws the npe
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // catch it and do nothing (or handle it!)
}
// ... the rest of your code
```

Comment: The code should be refactored in a way so that the `null` case is handled and caught before it throws any exceptions.

Comment: @f1sh that's true, but that doesn't sound like what the poster is asking. They're asking how to let the program to continue running after the npe is thrown. I agree though, they should take care of the npe rather than ignore it.